# Generating a Mac kernel core dump using NMI (Left-command + right command + power button)

Tags: macos, kernel, lldb, coredump

I am collecting information for bug reports for Mac OS 10.13 (High Sierra) betas and want to include core dumps with the reports.  I have set up core dump server to catch the core dumps using the information in TN2118 on Apple's developer site (you need a developer account to view this tech note).  I can generate a core dump file on the server if the test Mac encounters a kernel panic but not if I trigger it with an NMI (Non-Maskable Interrupt).

When I trigger the Mac with an NMI, I can connect to the test Mac using lldb on a second Mac but can't get the test Mac to send a core dump to the core dump server.

How do I get the NMI to generate the core dump and send it to the core dump server?  Is there a lldb command I can use to instruct the test Mac to send a core dump to the server?

Note: Your core dump server needs to be running the same version of Mac OS as the test Mac.  I tried for many hours to collect core dumps from Mac OS 10.13 with a server running Mac OS 10.11 and it failed every time.

Comment: What are your kernel `boot-args`?

Comment: Test:~ yoda$ nvram boot-args
boot-args debug=0xd44 -v kdp_match_name=en3 _panicd_ip=10.0.1.18

Comment: Note: there is no '-' at the end of the above line, it's just that i can't figure out how to add a blank line.